# Problem with date range filter

Tags: list, 2016, filter, date

I have implemented date range filter on my SharePoint 2016 list using date filter web part. The complete procedure you can find [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/filter-list-using-date-range-of-a-column-in-sharepoint/)

But after this implementation my list search  box vanished. Even in the edit web part under miscellaneous I am not able to find **display search box** option.

Any Idea, why search box got disable.

Comment: Which style you are using in the list web part view settings?

Comment: @GaneshSanap It is default only.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and to resolve the same, I had to enable the setting, *Miscellaneous -> Server Rendering* on the List View web part.

Comment: I had also enabled the server rendering. But it never worked.