# Implement date filter on a list

Tags: list, 2016, filter

I want to implement a date range filter on my sp2016 list, having two date fields (**To** and **From** date) and where a person can select the date range and filter the list data. I tried with the out of box date filter web part but it is causing some issue. Can anyone suggest some other way to implement a date range filter on a list. Thanks.

Comment: Write more you question, fiter date column, need change color items or group items?

Comment: @Fox I want to filter the list data on the basis of from and to date.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:

1. **By Creating View**:

   Sources:

   1. [How to Filter a SharePoint Date Column by Range](https://itgroove.net/mmman/2016/03/09/how-to-filter-a-sharepoint-date-column-by-range/)
   2. See "Filter on dynamic dates or current user" section in [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4).
2. **By Using SharePoint Designer**

   Source: [Filter List Using Date Range of a Column](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/f955eefb-250f-45d1-94ce-692ef74c89c0/filter-list-using-date-range-of-a-column-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thanks for the response. First approach is not what I want to implement. I want to have a date range filter on my list with two fields **TO** and **FROM** date and on the basis of dates selected on the date field users can filter the list data.

About the second approach I have tried the same thing but it is causing some issues on my list. I am not able to modify the list view, it gives the error that invalid date fields. And the search box also gets invisible form the list. As mentioned [here]( https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254100/problem-with-date-range-filter)